# Using a ferroresonant regulating transformer as an isolation transformer

Tags: transformer, safety, isolation

I'm looking to use a (surplus, NOS) Sola (catalog number 22212) ferroresonant voltage regulating transformer (120V primary and secondary) as a low-power isolation transformer (4A) in case I need to float some project.  Will this work?  What safety issues would I run into vs. using a designed-for-purpose isolation transformer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will work, and there shouldn't be any safety issues.

Just be aware:

- Ferroresonant transformers are horribly inefficient, so the input power will be considerably higher than the output power. (i.e., they get hot!)
- The output waveform is more like a square wave than a sine wave.
- The input power factor is horrendous.

These characteristics occur because the core is deliberately driven into saturation by the resonant winding in order to get the voltage-regulating effect.

Comment: The PF I'm not concerned about as long as the load it presents to the power network is roughly linear (simple leading or lagging PF is A-OK, piles of harmonics not so much).  Heat I know how to deal with (forced air, if nothing else!), and the squared output waveform won't bug modern gear one bit (SMPSen, AIUI, don't give a hoot about input waveforms).

Comment: It isn't a reactive power factor, it's a lot of harmonic distortion.